# Access H2 Embedded Database for WSO2 products

Tags: wso2, wso2-streaming-integrator

I am using stream processor 4.3.0 and need to access the H2 Database for it which comes by default in WSO2 SP application.

Can some please help me here to access/browse the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> And need to access the H2 Database for it which comes by default in WSO2 SP application

For WSO2SP DB configuration stored in:

```
${carbon.home}/conf/worker/deploymment.yaml
${carbon.home}/conf/dashboard/deploymment.yaml
${carbon.home}/conf/..other module../deploymment.yaml
```

so you can check the database locations

by default check

```
${carbon.home}/wso2/worker/database
${carbon.home}/wso2/dashboard/database
${carbon.home}/wso2/..other module../database
```

You can use [H2 Shell](http://opensource-soa.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-use-h2-shell.html) to access the databases

Please note the embedded H2 databases are not intended to be accessed from multiple processes concurrently, so stop the wso2sp first

Answer (score -2):

please  find the answer below.

1. Open the /repository/conf/carbon.xml file and paste the following configuration.
2. Do not uncomment the existing  element. Just paste the following configuration below it.

   `<H2DatabaseConfiguration>
           <property name="web"/>
           <property name="webPort">8082</property>
           <property name="webAllowOthers"/>

   </H2DatabaseConfiguration>`

3.Restart the WSO2 product and access the following URL via your browser: `http://localhost:8082`

Tip: If you are logged in to the management console, log out before connecting to the database.

4.Enter the following details and click Connect.

- JDBC URL : jdbc:h2:[file path to /repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB]
- username : wso2carbon
- password  : wso2carbon

Comment: Stream Processor does not have carbon.xml property file.

Comment: That would work for other (full carbon) products, but not wso2sp